# How to use catch and block in SMTP code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to use catch | block in the following code, please? When the form fields are complete and the Send button pressed, nothing happens. Whatever has been typed in in those fields simply remains there.

```
Private Sub SendEmail_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
SendEmail.Click

Dim myMessage As New MailMessage
Dim Smtpserver As New SmtpClient

Dim user_name As String = Request.Form("your_name") 'user_name is the 
TextBox ID
Dim user_email As String = Request.Form("your_email") 'user_email is the 
TextBox ID
Dim user_subject As String = Request.Form("your_subject") 'user_subject is 
the TextBox ID
Dim user_message As String = Request.Form("your_message") 'user_message is 
the TextBox ID

'Request.Form - extract data from form fields and create the mail message

myMessage.From = New MailAddress(user_email) 'User's email
myMessage.To.Add(New MailAddress("myEmail1@Mail.Com")) 'Webmaster
myMessage.CC.Add(New MailAddress("myEmail2@Mail.com")) 'Webmaster's 
assistant
myMessage.Subject = user_subject
myMessage.Body = user_message

myMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = 
DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
myMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
myMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High

Smtpserver.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
Smtpserver.Host = ("IP_add")
Smtpserver.Port = 25
Smtpserver.EnableSsl = False

Dim basicAuthenticationInfo As New 
System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@myPage.net", "Pwd")
Smtpserver.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo
'Smtpserver.UseDefaultCredentials = False
Smtpserver.Send(myMessage)

myMessage.Dispose()
myMessage = Nothing\
Smtpserver = Nothing

pnlFormFields.Visible = False
pnlThankYouMessage.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your problem lies somewhere else. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You use a `Catch` block in any code where you want to catch an exception. Where do you want to catch an exception in that code. If you don't know then you need to work that out first. SO is not simply a place for you to posy any block of code and we tell you how to add error handling. Debug your code and come back when you have a specific issue.

Comment: Setting a variable to `Nothing` is usually useless, especially local variables

Comment: The reason that the fields keep their content is causes by the ViewState. You should look into that since it's an integral part of webforms.

Comment: Hello Tim - are you referring to:  myMessage = Nothing
        Smtpserver = Nothing

Comment: When I put a breakpoint on Smtoserver.Send(myMessage), and go to StepInto, I get a yellow arrow in the left margin with this highlighted: typeof JSON!="undefined". Another error pops up in the Output pane: _references.js' not found. It is, in fact, there.